# Total sum based on Expression Detail Items (SUM IF Line Items)

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a table showing `Turnover`. 
I used the same column but did a `SUM IIF` on the detail lined as follows:
`=SUM(IIF(Fields!ID_Country.Value = 17,Fields!Turnover.Value,0))`
and
`=SUM(IIF(Fields!ID_Country.Value = 23,Fields!Turnover.Value,0))`

17 = Great Britain
23 = Ireland

I then want to do a TOTAL per column based on my above detail rows. I just cannot find the right way to do it. 
I Tried:

`SUM(=SUM(IIF(Fields!ID_Country.Value = 17,Fields!Turnover.Value,0)))`
But this does not work.

Please help as I am really stuck.

Thank you!

Because `Turnover` for GB is in Pounds and for Ireland they are in Euros, I want to split my columns and then do a final `SUM` for GB and Ireland.

I expect to see the grant total for per column for GB and Ireland summing my detail rows which have the `expression` calculation. (SUMIIF)

Table: Circled in RED is where I expect to see my TOTAL
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDBKn.png)

Data Structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIud2.jpg)

Comment: Please post your table structure and data to understand what you're asking

Comment: Hi, I have attached the data structure and the expected table above in my initial post. 
I have circled in RED where I expect to see the `TOTAL SUM` calculation.
Thanks.